# How to print my url into a popup

Tags: html, image, popup, click, area

Here is my clickable image in html

```
<img title="Sans titre." src="upload/docs/image/png/2014-10/sans_titre.png" alt="Sans titre" width="964" height="260" usemap="#map" />
<map name="map">
<area shape="rect" coords="545,45,567,65" href="www.google.fr" alt="txte alternatif" target="_parent" /> </map>
```

I'm looking how to get the click result into a popup and not in the current window, nor in a new tab.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to use jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('img').on('click', function() {
        window.alert("yourUrl");
      });
});
```

That way when you click the img it will alert a popup with yourUrl in it, indeed you have to change the yourUrl string in your URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can communicate with popup windows by keeping a reference of the window you opened. For example, this code opens a popup window and writes to it - you can also easily call methods in the popup window using popupReference.methodName (window scope).

Here is a simple example to help get you going:

**html**

```
<a href="#" id="popupopener">open</a>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="somethingToSend"></input><a href="#" id="popupwriter">send to popuop</a>
```

**js**

```
(function () {
    var popupReference = null;
    document.getElementById('popupopener').addEventListener('click', function () {
        popupReference = window.open("", null, "height=200,width=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");  
    });
    document.getElementById('popupwriter').addEventListener('click', function () {
        popupReference.document.write('<br/>' + document.getElementById('somethingToSend').value);
    });
})();
```

all together:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="#" id="popupopener">open</a>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="somethingToSend"></input><a href="#" id="popupwriter">send to popuop</a>
<script>
(function () {
    var popupReference = null;
    document.getElementById('popupopener').addEventListener('click', function () {
        popupReference = window.open("", null, "height=200,width=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");  
    });
    document.getElementById('popupwriter').addEventListener('click', function () {
        popupReference.document.write('<br/>' + document.getElementById('somethingToSend').value);
    });
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```